# Call A Jquery Function (Defined Globally) in a linked .js file from a page

Tags: jquery, function

I am trying to call a JQUERY function from a page which is defined in an external .js file called gallery.js

inside gallery.js

```
function show_home(){
  //Does Something
}
$(function(){
 // Some more functions
});
```

Now in mypage.php

```
<?php
  echo '<script>';
  switch($getval){
    case: 'something' : 
    echo 'show_home();';
    break;
  }
  echo '</script>';
?>
```

This call gives me a  **function not found error**

Kindly help me fix this.

Thanks

Regards
**Genocide_hoax**

**UPDATE**

The Problem has resolved. There was a silly mistake it my code which I corrected and yhe code above works perfectly. Sorry to bother you all.

Thanks

Comment: Make sure `gallery.js` is loaded before this PHP code.

Answer (score 2):

In your PHP code, the way you are calling it is as if show_home() is a function defined in PHP. i.e. You are trying to call `show_home()` from PHP itself instead of rendering it and letting the browser call it.

You should instead do:

```
<?php
  echo '<script>';
  switch($getval){
    case: 'something' : echo 'show_home();';
    break;
  }
  echo '</script>';
?>
```

That will generate the following output when rendered (assuming `$getval` is `something`)

```
<script>show_home();</script>
```

Comment: Ahh, Din see you comment. edited the answer further for no reason.. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its resolved. There was a silly mistake in my code. Fixed it and everything is working as expected. Thanks anyways. Sorry to bother you.